# Создание экземпляра параметризированного класса с использованием рефлексии

Tags: java, рефлексия, dependency-injection, аннотации

Пишу свою реализацию DependencyInjection с использованием аннотаций и инициализацией сущностей с помощью рефлексии.

С помощью аннотаций получаю полное имя класса из properties и с помощью рефлексии создаю экземпляр необходимого класса, далее сетаю в необходимое поле.

Возникла проблема, необходимо получить экземпляр параметризированного класса, как пример ArrayList<>.
Получаю класс, которым параметризированно поле "class java.lang.Integer" или для всего поля "java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>".

Как имея подобную информацию получить экземпляр необходимого класса и надо ли вообще в таком случае создавать параметризированный класс или использовать сырые типы. Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста реализацию))

Answer (score 0):

для создания экземпляра параметры типа уже не нужны;
если Вы получаете класс через поле

```
field.getGenericType()
```

и это Class, то можно создавать

```
cls.newInstance()
```

примеры реализации:

- https://github.com/square/dagger
- https://github.com/weld